# Excle HELP. fill blank rows from excel file1 to file2 with an identical column values as reference

Tags: excel, function

I have two files of excel.

file1 has 50,000rows
file2 has 10,000rows

both files have the same columns.
example.
 
==>file1 has column A, B, C, D while column A, B, C are blank and column D has same values with file2 column D.
==>file2 has column A, B, C, D while column A, B, C have values need to fill to (file1 column A, B, C) and column D has same values with file1 column D but for random rows only because file1 has only 10,000rows compare to fil2 has 50,000rows.

I wan't to ask help for excel function to automatically fill blank rows from file1 column A,B, C with the reference column D as they have same values.

sample data:
file1
1  A            B            C            D            
2                                                                text1
3                                                                text2
.                                                                 .....
 
.                                                                 .....
50,000                                text50,000

sample data:
file2
1  A            B            C            D            
2 dog       cat         tiger                           text1
3 gold      rose       silver     text215
.                                                                 .....
 
.                                                                 .....
10,000                                text10,000

I tried this IF statement but it seems not works if column D not match and also not work if drag the formula to copy to the next rows.
file1 cell (A2)

```
=IF(D2=[file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$D$2, [file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2,)
```

file1 cell (B2)

```
=IF(D2=[file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$D$2, [file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$2,)
```

file1 cell (C2)

```
=IF(D2=[file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$D$2, [file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$C$2,)
```

Please help what is the right excel function to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all values in column `D` file1 has corresponding value in column `D` file2, than use this one in file1 cell `A2`:

`=INDEX([file2.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,MATCH($D2,[file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$D:$D,0))`

and drag it down and across.

Otherwise you could use this one (for Excel 2007 and later):

`=IFERROR(INDEX([file2.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,MATCH($D2,[file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$D:$D,0)),"not found")`

if value from column `D` file1 not found in column `D` file2 it returns `"not found"`.

For Excel 2003:

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX([file2.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,MATCH($D2,[file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$D:$D,0))), "not found", INDEX([file2.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,MATCH($D2,[file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$D:$D,0)))`